# Loading content from Wordpress posts dynamically from clicked images

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to insert content from separate Wordpress posts into an info box when an image is clicked. I'm using a modified template for this section of the site, where the images are populated from an array.

I have successfully made this work using the `.load()` method with jQuery and a static URL.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('.dynagrid a').click(function(event){ 
                // stop normal link click
                event.preventDefault(); 
                }); 
            jQuery('.dynagrid a').click(function(){
                jQuery('div.project-info').fadeToggle(function(){
                    jQuery(".infotext").load('/cowshed/akg .infotext > *', function() {
                        jQuery('div.project-info').fadeToggle() 
                    }); 
                });
            });
        });
```

My problem lies in making the loaded URL dynamic for each image - with each image loading different information. My plan was to grab the `<alt>` information for each image as a variable and insert this e.g. `jQuery(".infotext").load('/cowshed/+alt+ .infotext >*');` and match it to the permalink of the desired post but everything I've tried has failed.

I've looked for hours for a solution on this and I fear my inexperience in jQuery is making this much harder than it may actually be.

Here's the page so far: [Cowshed Tools](http://www.cowpress.co.uk/cowshed/tools)

Can anyone see a solution and shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery(".infotext").load('/cowshed/akg .infotext > *', function() {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The indicated part should be the URL that'll provide the content you're loading into the .infotext element. You've got what looks like an unholy mishmash of url and CSS selectors, which is NOT a valid URL. Given you want to load things dynamically, it should be something:

```
.load('http://example.com/fetchcontent?contentID=' + this.alt, function () ....);
```

The url doesn't have to be absolute like that, but it should be a valid URL for your server.

Comment: Haha thank you for your honesty. This does seem to make sense. Does the `+ this.alt,` section require 'alt' to already be a variable containing the relevant images alt text? I tried `var imgAlt = $(this).find('img').attr("alt", function(){` to happen as the image is clicked but this seems to break my perfectly working `preventDeafault` function on the image. Any further help would be much appreciated.